# How does FromQueryAttribute actually work and why do I need it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working with some pre-existing code that uses an HttpGet endpoint to get all comments. It takes some default parameters and before each parameter it is decorated with a `[FromQuery]` attribute. I'm a little confused about why we need this here and what it really does for me.

There isn't much online all I found was this documentation:
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

This doesn't answer my question though...

- What is a query string?
- How is it used in endpoints?
- When is it that I don't need to specify this attribute? I don't see it being used very much.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FooResponse), 200),
public async Task<ActionResult<FooResponse>> GetAll([FromQuery]string sortColumn = "CommentId",
    [FromQuery]SortDirections sortDirection = SortDirections.Asc, 
    [FromQuery]string filter = "", 
    [FromQuery]int page = 1, 
    [FromQuery]int pageSize = 10)
{
    var data = await _mediator.Send(new GetAllComments(sortColumn, sortDirection, filter, page, pageSize));
.
.
.
    return Ok(data);
}
```

I suspect that it has something to do with what is passed into the URL but I'm not quite sure...

Comment: You are correct, it does have something to do with URL, if you didn't already know, `QueryString Parameters` are anything in the URL that comes after ? and are followed by some variable = some value, so something like this, http://www.sometestsite.com?id=3, id would be a query string parameter, by decorating your method parameters, it tells the method that it should be included in the query string parameters of the request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage here is superfluous. The action would function the same without `[FromQuery]` being applied to all the params, as it only responds to GET requests.

> What is a query string?

The query string is the portion of the URI after the `?` character is applied. It constitutes a data portion of a URI versus a pure routing portion.

> How is it used in endpoints?

The question here is a little tenuous, so it would be more appropriate to ask "How is it used in a request?" The answer to that it is a way to pass data along with a GET request to a particular URI. Unlike other HTTP methods, GET does not really allow a request "body". (Actually, the spec technically *does* allow this, but it's almost universally not implemented that way.)

> When is it that I don't need to specify this attribute? I don't see it being used very much.

Again, a better question is "When do I actually need to specify this attribute?" The answer to that is basically when it's ambiguous where the data is coming from. This will almost invariably be with other HTTP methods such as POST. By default, data is expected to come from the request body there, and depending on the content type of that request body, the binding is expected to be either `FromForm` or `FromBody`, which will usually be the default for params there. (Which is the default depends on whether you're dealing with a traditional MVC-style controller or an API-style controller.) If you need to actually get a particular param from the query string instead of the body in such a scenario, then you would apply the `[FromQuery]` attribute to that particular param.

Answer (score 3):

Since the action in your post is for GET requests only ([HttpGet]) the [FromQuery] isn't necessary - the parameters will automatically use the associated query string values.

For POST actions ([HttpPost]) this attribute specifies to grab the value from the query string as opposed to the data which was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Query string is a part of the URL that comes after an `?` and it provides a way to pass values as a list of key-value pairs, each pair separated by `&` characters. Say you have the following URL:

`http://mywebsite.com/somePage?a=123&b=Hello&c=World`

So the query string part int that URL corresponds to `a=123&b=Hello&c=World`, and the list of key-value pairs that were passed was:

```
a = 123
b = Hello
c = World
```

ASP.NET Core can bind values to variables in a lot of different ways, and one of them is by reading values from a query string and converting/assigning these values to the values of your API's methods. To specify that a parameter should come from the query string, you use the [FromQuery] attribute.

So - for instance - when you have `[FromQuery]string sortColumn = "CommentId"` you are basically telling it to read the `sortColumn` key from the query string and assign it to the `sortColumn` parameter of the `GetAll()` method, and if that "sortColumn" key is not present in the query string, it should be assigned the default "CommentId" value. It is similar to the other parameters.

So you could access that URL with something like that (you should use the correct URL to get to your GetAll method, which I can't tell with the code you have provided):

`http://your-system-url-here/GetAll?page=2&pageSize=20`

Which would assing the `page` parameter a value of `2` and the `pageSize` parameter a size of `20`.